# View to top of ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a scrollview with a linear layout. Inside of the linear layout I add 5 items (Linear layouts with some views). When inflated they are bigger than the screen.

I want when the screen renders, the item 5 (last item) show at the top of the screen. How to do it?

I've tried:

```
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, item.getBottom());
       }
    });
    }
```

But it doesn't work. I've inspected geTop(), getBottom(), getScrollY(), in my views, but all returned 0.

This is my parent layout:

```
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/suggested_menu_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/suggested_menu_meals_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

    </ScrollView>
```

This my item layout:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/linear_suggested_meal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/cardview_default_radius"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress_suggested_meal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/cards_padding_space">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/suggested_meal_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black_soft"
                    android:text="Sugestão de café da manhã"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/suggested_meal_total_points"
                    style="@style/DSTextLarge"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/suggested_meal_name"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@id/suggested_meal_name"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/suggested_meal_name"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/zero"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/green_x"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/suggested_meal_suggested"
                    style="@style/DSTextSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/suggested_meal_total_points"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/suggested_meal_total_points"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/suggested_meal_total_points"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:text="sugerido de "
                    android:textColor="@color/gray_opaque" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/separator_suggested_meal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/suggested_meal_total_points"
                    android:background="@color/dividers" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/suggested_meal_food_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/separator_suggested_meal"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:paddingTop="3dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/suggested_meal_food_container"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/button_suggested_meal_next_suggestion"
                        style="@style/DSLinkButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/button_suggested_meal_add"
                        style="@style/DSLinkButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/horizontal_space_large"
                        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:text="@string/button_meal_suggestion_label_add_suggest" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try .scrollTo() instead of .smoothScrollTo()

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }
});
```

Comment: This scrolls to the end, I need the view to be right on the top! Thanks!

Comment: scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);

Comment: I need a particular View been on top, like an anchor on the web! TIA. :)